# putting a function into td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to put a javascript function into  to place the value into it but I am having a bit of trouble.

HTML

```
<table class="table table-borderless table-hover table-responsive">
     <thead class="thead-inverse">
           <tr>
               <th>Order Number</th>
               <th>Company Name</th>
               <th>Symbol</th>
               <th>Bought Price</th>
              <th>Current Price</th>
               <th>Shares</th>
               <th>Profit</th>
               <th>Type of Stock</th>
               <th></th>
            </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <?php
      while($transarray = mysqli_fetch_array($_SESSION['trans'])){
       echo
       "<tr>
        <td>".'trans_num'."</td>
        <td>".'stock_name'."</td>
        <td>".'stock_ticker'."</td>
        <td>". 'stock_bp'."</td>
        <td class='stockprofit'>"."."."</td>
        <td>".'stock_shares'."</td>
        <td>".'stock_change'."</td>
        <td>".'stock_type'."</td>
        <td><button class='sellButton btn btn-primary' data-target='#modalsell' id='sellStock'>Sell Stock</button></td>
        </tr>";
       }
    ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

With this, I am trying to pass the current  to the function and find the position of stock_ticker cell to do some other functions. But ticker is a blank object when I try to use **find("td:nth-child(3)").text()**. Could this be because the table has not fully finish processing before the function is called?

I've tried using `<td onload='function(stock_sticker)'>...</td>` but did not work when I place alert within the function to test it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.stockprofit').each(function({$(this).html(getPrices($(this)))}));
});

function getPrices(e){
    return 'test';
}
```

Nothing on my table

Comment: nothing to do with php

Comment: The entire html table please. And the element that has your selected class.

Comment: sorry I fixed it, imma try to fix the spacing, and the element is the `<td class='stockprofit'>"."."."</td>`

Comment: As was told 2 days ago, this is not a PHP problem. Post your HTML code.

Comment: That is my HTML code. The html is part of a PHP file that does database get info with inclusion of HTML for my page. I don't know what's more for the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $(this) refers to the dom element currently. jQuery functions like each() let you pass a function which receives the current element.

```
   <table class="table table-borderless table-hover table-responsive">
     <thead class="thead-inverse">
           <tr>
               <th>Order Number</th>
               <th>Company Name</th>
               <th>Symbol</th>
               <th>Bought Price</th>
              <th>Current Price</th>
               <th>Shares</th>
               <th>Profit</th>
               <th>Type of Stock</th>
               <th></th>
            </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <?php
       echo
       "<tr>
        <td>".'trans_num'."</td>
        <td>".'stock_name'."</td>
        <td>".'stock_ticker'."</td>
        <td>". 'stock_bp'."</td>
        <td class='stockprofit'>"."."."</td>
        <td>".'stock_shares'."</td>
        <td>".'stock_change'."</td>
        <td>".'stock_type'."</td>
        <td><button class='sellButton btn btn-primary' data-target='#modalsell' id='sellStock'>Sell Stock</button></td>
        </tr>";

    ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.stockprofit').each(function(){$(this).html(getPrices($(this)));
        });
            $('#sellStock').click(  function(){  
        });
    });
        var child = 0;

    function getPrices(e){
        console.log(e);
        child++;console.log(child);
        console.log(e.closest('tr').find("td:nth-child("+child+")").text());
    var ticker = e.closest('tr').find("td:nth-child(3)").text();
    //alert(ticker);
    return ticker;
}
</script>
```

Comment: My apologies for the late reply, but does not seem to do anything. I don't think it's calling the function correctly when I try to return a test string

Comment: open your console you will see a log when you refresh your page.

Comment: why did you change ur getPrices... add the lines in my edit.

Comment: Just curious, what is 'child' variable in this sense? Seems like just an open variable since my console is empty. I am using Bracket and looking at Debug -> Dev's Tool to look at Console, but empty on Chrome as well.

Comment: complete code up there. copy paste it in a file and run it in browser. you should see expected output.

Comment: Thank you!! It works when I place the javascript within the HTML/PHP file, but I am going to try and put it back in JS, didnt work at first, and see what happens. :D